# PHPUnit and Selenium - run tests from another class

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I am using PHPUnit and Selenium to test my web application.

At the moment I have 2 test classes - **UserTest** and **PermissionsTest**.

- In **UserTest** I have methods which test that the program can successfully create a new user.
- In **PermissionsTest** I turn certain permissions on and off and test the outcome.

For instance, I might turn the 'Create User' permission off and then test that the 'Create User' button is disabled. However, if I turn the 'Create User' permission back on, I want to test that it is possible to create a user.

All of the logic for being able to create a user is already in the UserTest class - so is there any way of running tests from the UserTest class from the PermissionsTest class?

At the moment I am trying the following code:

```
public function testUserPermission(){
  $userTest = new UserTest();
  if($this->hasPermission = true){
    $userTest->testCanCreateUser();
  }
}
```

However when I run this test, I get the error `"There is currently no active session to execute the 'execute' command. You're probably trying to set some option in setup() with an incorrect setter name..."`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was as follows:

```
//instantiate and set up other test class
$userTest = new UserTest();
$userTest->setUpSessionStrategy($this::$browsers[0]);
$userTest->prepareSession();

//carry out a test from this class
$userTest->testCanCreateUser();
```

This works nicely. I can't see why using functionality from another test class is a bad idea in this case, because if I didn't do that I'd have to just rewrite that functionality into my new class, which seems less 'pure'...

Comment: How did you include the class? Was it autoloaded by PHPUnit or did it require a manual directive?

Comment: I used autoloading to include the "UserTest" class. Specifically I used composer to create an autoload file and included this file in the PHPUnit "bootstrap" file.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if something similar would work for Selenium 1? I just discovered that `setUpSessionStrategy` and `prepareSession` are Webdriver-specific commands only.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about Selenium 1 as I have never used it - I hope you find the answer!

Comment: I found the necessary commands to emulate what you did in your answer - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you're missing separation of your test implementation with its logic - I'm not talking about PHP issue but general test model.It will allow you to reuse your test components in various test cases.

You can take a look on some 
material about Page Objects in PHP [here](http://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/selenium-best-practices/) or general selenium [wiki](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

For Selenium 1 (RC),

I made the following modifications instead (as well as applying the Page Object design pattern):

Specific Test class

```
//instantiate and set up other test class
$userTest = new UserTest($this->getSessionId());

//carry out a test from this class
$userTest->createUser();

//asserts as normal
$userTest->assertTextPresent();
...
```

Base Page Object class

```
class PageObject extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase {
    public function __construct($session_id) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setSessionId($session_id);
        $this->setBrowserUrl(BASE_URL);
    }
}
```

Specific Page Object class

```
class UserTest extends PageObject {

    public function createUser() {
        // Page action
    }
}
```